# I am having an issue with Python Selenium Webdriver not detecting an element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have tried multiple ways of finding the specific element on the web page that I am looking for. See above the "test1", I tried 4 different options. No matter what I do I get the no such element exception, even when it does exist.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os

pathz =  os.path.expanduser(os.sep.join(["~","Desktop\\Dell Driver Scraper\\Output\\"]))

for file in os.scandir(pathz):
    if file.name.endswith(".txt"):
        os.unlink(file.path)

os.makedirs(os.path.expanduser(os.sep.join(["~","Desktop\\Dell Driver Scraper\\Output\\"])), exist_ok=True)


product_code = 'inspiron-15-5593-laptop'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(f'https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/{product_code}/drivers')

driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(3)



#test1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.card.border-left-0.border-right-0.border-top-0.d-none.pb-7.mb-8.mt-8')
#test1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'card.border-left-0.border-right-0.border-top-0.d-none.pb-7.mb-8.mt-8')
#test1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='card border-left-0 border-right-0 border-top-0 d-none pb-7 mb-8 mt-8']")
#test1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card border-left-0 border-right-0 border-top-0 d-none pb-7 mb-8 mt-8']")
print(test1)
```

It in the pages code as:

`<div class="card border-left-0 border-right-0 border-top-0 d-none pb-7 mb-8 mt-8" id="win10Banner">`

It exists, and yet I get the exception saying that it does not.

I do not understand why it cannot find it and was hoping for some help on this issue.

I need the code to detect whether or not "card border-left-0 border-right-0 border-top-0 d-none pb-7 mb-8 mt-8" exists. Which is obviously failing when it says it does not exist when it does.

`test1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.card.border-left-0.border-right-0.border-top-0.d-none.pb-7.mb-8.mt-8')`

`test1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'card.border-left-0.border-right-0.border-top-0.d-none.pb-7.mb-8.mt-8')`

`test1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='card border-left-0 border-right-0 border-top-0 d-none pb-7 mb-8 mt-8']")`

`test1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card border-left-0 border-right-0 border-top-0 d-none pb-7 mb-8 mt-8']")`

These are the things that I have tried and each one gives the same error.

Comment: The URL to the website I am working with is: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/inspiron-15-5593-laptop/drivers

I tried to put it in the question but the question was being marked as spam

Comment: remember that class names are not necessarily unique... those are just css styles.  The element has an ID attribute which is designed to be unique, so you should be using that in your selector... ex: //div[@id='win10Banner']

Answer (score 0):

after having a look you need to select check for updates first before the element becomes avilable on the page heres how to do that.

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "btn-detect-drivers")))
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "btn-detect-drivers")  
print(button.text)
button.click()
```

Problem is before the element avilable you will also need to close/handle the pop which appears after then it should appear on the page and become interactable. If you need anymore help let me know.